# RedBeanPHP 3.5 REST server

Tags: rest, redbean

reading the documentation at http://www.redbeanphp.com/rest_server I found:

> In RedBeanPHP 3.5 you can use the new Resty BeanCan Server

and:

> The Resty BeanCan Server works with a reference bean. For instance a $user

So if I'm right, the second parameter of the handleREST method is always in relation to the reference bean (first param.)

But how to use it directly with the needed model / bean, like (taking GET as an example) in the legacy rest server:

```
$server->handleRESTGetRequest('/book'); //returns books
```

In few words I don't get the purpose of the first parameter; I'd just use it like this:

```
$can->handleREST('user/2', 'GET'); 
// or
$can->handleREST('user/list', 'GET');
```

...but does not seem to be possible

Thanks.